# how to disable status bar or notification bar but not disable title bar in android?

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, titlebar

I want to disable status bar or notification bar in android. I use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` for disable it but it makes my title bar disable too. how can I only disable status bar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a base activity with  below code in onCreate function and extend that activity every time

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Or

you can have above code in every activity for having Title bar visible but status bar invisible.

EDIT: Just make sure you don't define any theme in your Android Manifest.

Comment: doesn't work bro. It does same as the Fullscreen attribute. It hides everything.

Comment: but title bar remain there and status bar gone

Comment: Well, I tried your solution but it shows none of them. Can anyone else give any feedback?

Comment: @YogeshSomani check out screen shot, please check your menifest for any kind of theme given or not http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fcsm15&s=6

Comment: yes I have defined android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
 in my manifest. I tried with Fullscreen too. None worked.

Comment: @YogeshSomani please remove that theme from manifest file and just keep above code in you every activity's onCreate function in starting.

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani thanks one rajkotian always give +1 to other rajkotian :)

Comment: Ok, it works. It works if we don't define any theme in manifest. You should have clarified that.

Comment: @ChintanRaghwani send you request in FB

Answer (score 1):

Use the full screen theme in your manifest and then 
You can defined a separate layout with your title in it then use the include tag on every layout in your app.

Answer (score 0):

1. No Title Bar No Status bar, showing Full Screen Android (Mostly used in Games)

res->values->styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Application Manifest.xml:

```
:
:
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" 
                 >
:
:
```

Result: Full screen without titlebar and status bar
[image]

2. No Title bar showing only Phone status bar
   Same file just remove ".Fullscreen"

   res->values->styles.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
           <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
   </style>

   </resources>
   ```

Result: It will show only Status bar without full title bar
[image]

3. Showing Status bar and title bar

res->values->styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme">
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try this one in your manifest file:

```
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: He wants to keep the titlebar

Comment: @Nunu Then, What's the status bar in android mobile?

Comment: @SpK Status bar means top bar contains with notification icon, network signal icons and etc..

Comment: well I think if Title bar has to be visible , then status bar will be automatically visible.

Comment: @AndroidCoader I know that. User @Nunu tells that "he wants to keep the titlebar" So, user should use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` for his required style.

Comment: I can't find anything on Google which exactly answers this question.